# empty control sequence in \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: expl3, xparse, csname

In the code below, `\csname ... \endcsname` and `\cs_if_exist_use:c` inside `\NewDocumentCommand` do not behave as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\expandafter\def\csname test 1\endcsname{a,$\alpha$,b}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_test_clist
\NewDocumentCommand {\test} {}
  {
    \csname test 1\endcsname
    \cs_if_exist_use:c {test 1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
show: \test

use: \csname test 1\endcsname
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you defined a command with name `test 1` but within Expl3 code space characters are ignored and make no tokens so you tested `test1`  use `test ~ 1`  to have a space token between test and 1.